# Firestore query Cursors Generating Dynamic Queries

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore when I am writing the query and executing like this , it is working fine

```
_query = query(collectionTestingRef, 
     where('name','==', 'him') , 
     limit(4));
```

But when I am taking the query in some variable and then using (required because I need to run a loop and add unknown where condition), it is not working.

```
var _localWherequery = "where('name','==', 'him')" ; 
_query = query(collectionTestingRef, 
    _localWherequery, 
    limit(4));
```

How can I achieve this dynamism, knowing that I don't know number of where clauses and I want to use query cursors only in Firestore.

Comment: Hi does my answer help? if yes acknowledge it and if not then we can solve it further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t just wrap `where` clause conditions within strings in the `_localWherequery` variable. Because Firestore will be unable to interpret it as a query filter.

Instead, you can create a function that takes a list of where clauses and builds a Firestore query dynamically.

This is just a example you can modify at your will:

```
import { collection, getDocs, limit, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./config/firebase.js";

const ref = collection(db, "users");
const whereClause = where("name", "==", "him");
const queryLimits = limit(2);
const q = query(ref, whereClause, queryLimits);
const snaps = await getDocs(q);
snaps.docs.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.id, " --> ", doc.data()));
```

Although you can also use some different methods to create custom queries, One of the methods mentioned is below. **Make note** that doing in below way will lose all the inference as method arguments will became of type `any`:

```
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./config/firebase.js";
function buildQuery(collectionRef, whereClauses) {
  let q = query(
    collectionRef,
    ...whereClauses.map((clause) =>
      where(clause.field, clause.operator, clause.value)
    )
  );
  return q;
}
const ref = collection(db, "users");
const whereClauses = [
  { field: "name", operator: "==", value: "him" },
  { field: "age", operator: ">=", value: 18 },
  { field: "gender", operator: "==", value: "male" },
];
const q = buildQuery(ref, whereClauses);
const snaps = await getDocs(q);
snaps.docs.forEach((doc) => console.log(doc.id, " --> ", doc.data()));
```

Reference: [**Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)