# Firestore query object with dynamic where and order clause

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

i am dynamically generating where clause and it is working fine .  referring to this solution  : [Firestore query Cursors Generating Dynamic Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975145/firestore-query-cursors-generating-dynamic-queries/75976718#75976718)

```
        function buildQueryNew(collectionRef ,  whereClauses , _limit) {
           let q = query(
             collectionRef,
             ...whereClauses.map((clause) =>
             where(clause[0], '==', clause[1])),
               limit(_limit)
             )
           return q;
         }
```

But when i am adding the orderBy Clause it is not working .

```
        function buildQueryNew(collectionRef ,  whereClauses  , sortField,sortOrder , _limit) {
               let q = query(
                 collectionRef,
                 ...whereClauses.map((clause) =>
                 where(clause[0], '==', clause[1])),
                 orderBy(sortField,sortOrder),
                   limit(_limit)
                 )
               return q;
             }
```

Also i have seen if i remove the whereClause map then orderBy is working fine,  its like they both are not working together , anything wrong i am doing  ?

whereClause Sample:  [
[
"name",
"himanshu"
]
]

[image]

Screenshot below for database :

[image]

Comment: What are the values of `sortField` and `sortOrder` when you call `buildQueryNew`?

Comment: sortField : "name" and sortOrder : "desc" .

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. What value does `clause[0]` hold?

Comment: Did you define the necessary index for the query? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: But orderBy is working without where clause , anyways let me try that also .

Comment: Yes, that's why you need an index,

Comment: Same result , wither where clause is working or the orderby clause . Let me try more . Thanks for your efforts , incase i found some solution i will paste here .